# tkinter. checkbutton. How to understand what the user has chosen?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter.checkbutton

What should I do if the further development of my program depends on the selected "Checkbutton" ? What condition should I write down so that it is ahead of which Checkbutton the user clicked on??

```
c1 = IntVar()
c2 = IntVar()
c3 = IntVar()
c4 = IntVar()

che1 = Checkbutton( text="Первый флажок", variable=c1, font=('Arial', 24), onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
che2 = Checkbutton( text="Второй флажок", variable=c2, font=('Arial', 24), onvalue=2, offvalue=0)
che3 = Checkbutton( text="Третий флажок", variable=c3, font=('Arial', 24), onvalue=3, offvalue=0)
che4 = Checkbutton( text="Третий флажок", variable=c3, font=('Arial', 24), onvalue=4, offvalue=0)
che1.place(x=10, y=200)
che2.place(x=10, y=250)
che3.place(x=10, y=300)
che3.place(x=10, y=350)
```

Comment: The user can check more than one button at a time. Are you wanting a list of the values of the checked checkbuttons?

Comment: There is not enough here to provide a good answer. Are you wanting the users to only be able to select one at a time? Are you wanting the user to be able to select multiple? Based on this we can work out the best logic to ID what is selected and what method you should use.

Answer (score 0):

So here is a general use version of what you want.

First we define everything in a list to make it easier to add or remove options and easier to review what is selected.

In this case we use a list to hold your label names and then based on the index of those labels we set the `Checkbutton` location.

From there you can take the `selected` list and iterate over it to decide what to do next in your code.

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
str_list = ["Первый флажок", "Второй флажок", "Третий флажок", "Третий флажок"]
c_list = []
selected = []

for ndex, value in enumerate(str_list):
    i = tk.IntVar()
    c = tk.Checkbutton(text=value, variable=i, font=('Arial', 24), onvalue=ndex + 1, offvalue=0)
    c_list.append([i, c, ndex])
    c_list[-1][1].grid(row=ndex, column=0)


def check_selected():
    global selected
    selected = []
    for lst in c_list:
        if lst[0].get() != 0:
            selected.append(lst[1]['text'])
            print(f'IntVar Value: {lst[0].get()}', f' - Label: {lst[1]["text"]}', f' - List index: {lst[2]}')


tk.Button(root, text='Selections', command=check_selected).grid(row=len(str_list), column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

```
IntVar Value: 1  - Label: Первый флажок  - List index: 0
IntVar Value: 3  - Label: Третий флажок  - List index: 2
```